# psexec on XP - Can't use switches...?

Tags: windows-xp, psexec

All I'm trying to do is execute this command:

```
psexec –sid c:\sysint\procexp.exe
```

On a machine running XP SP3 (Trying to find out why domain login takes 5 mins).

But no matter how I arrange them, as soon as I use one of the switches, i.e. '-s', psexec returns:

```
psexec could not start ?s:

(Or replace the 's' in that response for what ever the first switch was)
(Yep... procexp.exe is in the c:\sysint folder)
```

Is it just me?
I know that the command is correct. I'm running it as local administrator account.

Why on earth is it seeing the switch as the command to execute?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do “-” options work in other programs?  Do you maybe have some non-standard keyboard or key encoding setup that causes the “-” key to generate something other than the “-” character?

Comment: Is everything else on the host working well, or are there 'quirks'? Could be symptoms of leftover malware that messed with your system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you must be making some type of typo or have a corrupt file as I did your exact command (Ok, different path for process explorer) on my XP machine and it ran fine:

[image]